# tablelayout - 3 rows x 4 columns - each cell with TextView,Editview and Spinner

Tags: android, layout

Good Morning,

I am trying to design a layout and I am wondering if it possible at all.

I think I want a TableLayout with 3 rows and 4 columns. Then within each cell I want to have a TextView with an EditView below the TextView and then a spinner below the EditView. The objective is for a user to enter values and then select a unit of measurement, like inches or millimeters. The TextView is going to identify the name of parameter, the user then enters a number and selects the unit of measurement.

I first tried to get the three things (TextView, EditView and Spinner) to be underneath each other with no success. I can get the textview and the editview working but when I add the spinner it does not showup. I can get the TextView, EditView and two buttons working and I can get spinners working but for the life of me I can't get the TextView,EditView and Spinner working together although I get no errors when debugging or running. I trying this within a RelativeView so I can stack the 3 things together. My thought is that if I can get RelativeView working that I can then put it inside a tableview and get 3 rows of 4 inputs accross or 12 total parameters.

Does this make sense? Is this the right approach to create a way of inputting parameters, the reason I trying this instead of some linearview is I want to see all the values at one time on a nice grid like layout.

I anxiously await of assistance, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously I'm not getting into setting unique ids or layout height/widths for all the elements, but this is the structure:

```
<TableLayout>
  <TableRow>
    <LinearLayout
      android:orientation="horizontal">
      <include layout="@layout/form_fields" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
      android:orientation="horizontal">
      <include layout="@layout/form_fields" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
      android:orientation="horizontal">
      <include layout="@layout/form_fields" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
      android:orientation="horizontal">
      <include layout="@layout/form_fields" />
    </LinearLayout>
  </TableRow>
  <TableRow>
    <LinearLayout
      android:orientation="horizontal">
      <include layout="@layout/form_fields" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
      android:orientation="horizontal">
      <include layout="@layout/form_fields" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
      android:orientation="horizontal">
      <include layout="@layout/form_fields" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
      android:orientation="horizontal">
      <include layout="@layout/form_fields" />
    </LinearLayout>
  </TableRow>
  <TableRow>
    <LinearLayout
      android:orientation="horizontal">
      <include layout="@layout/form_fields" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
      android:orientation="horizontal">
      <include layout="@layout/form_fields" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
      android:orientation="horizontal">
      <include layout="@layout/form_fields" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
      android:orientation="horizontal">
      <include layout="@layout/form_fields" />
    </LinearLayout>
  </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Then your @layout/form_fields looks like this:

```
<LinearLayout
  android:orientation="vertical">
  <TextView />
  <EditText />
  <Spinner />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: i am amazed at your quick response.  I am working on digesting this now but I wanted to jump on and say 'Thanks'